# Examples for good Frequent Flyer / Loyalty Program pages

Tags: gui-design, web

I'm looking for good Frequent Flyer / Loyalty / Rewards program pages.

I'm talking about the "My Account" pages displaying current status and how long till we reach the next "level". (You know, usually you accumulate points to move from Bronze to Silver to Gold).

I saw Starbucks are doing a nice job. Do you have any other screenshots I can look at?

Comment: It would be great if the downvoter could post a comment. There are numerous heavily trafficked questions on the site that ask for "examples of x", such as this one: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4796/worst-ui-youve-ever-used I don't see faruz doing anything unusual in asking this question.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's because this is a "list of" type question where every answer is (potentially) equally valid. You also tend to get peoples favourite (or least favourite in this case) example - see the [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask). However, a properly phrased question would be OK.

Comment: @Chris. See the question I linked to - every answer equally valid, no single actual answer, yet look at the stats for it. I'm leery about us applying the rules only sometimes.

Comment: @Gary - the question you linked to has been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that is relatively intuitive, you can't go far wrong taking some inspiration from the MMORPG or other level based games (e.g. World of Warcraft) which give each character an experience bar to denote their level and indicate how far until the next one.

The basic layout is something like

```
(BRONZE) ===============|--------------------------- (SILVER)
CURRENT    (35/100) 75 Airmiles until next level.    **shiny!**
```

This basically depicts that the current level is on the left, with the desired level on the right. With a graphical bar representation of the progress stretching between (denoting the percent complete). Then either within, on-hover or beneath, the fine grained detail about how many air miles they need to complete until the next level.

While not probably relevant for flying, if you have consistent increments, you may find it better to depict as those instead. E.g. flights probably differ in the number of airmiles gained per flight. But if you do it simply on quantity of flights (rather than distance), you could say "6 more flights until next level". If you so wish, you could change the bar into an appropriate number of icons (e.g. aeroplanes) that "light up" (un-fade) as you progress through the level.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Onepass progress box]

The screenshot above is what I see when I log into my Continental Onepass account. I think that for some users, the placement of the progress-bar labels could be confusing. You might think that in my example, I had already reached silver-level, when in fact I'm only 30% complete. I roughly mocked-up a possible solution to this problem. See below:

[image]